# Why isn't Android Studio recognizing that I have created a 'menu' file?

Tags: android, menu

I am trying to create an options menu in Android Studio. I created the menu in res/ directory the normal way and named it main_menu.xml.
Directory:

[image]

Here is my code for the main_menu file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_add"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_add_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/add_note"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

However, in MainActivity.java, I am not able to get Android to recognize its presence, in the onCreateOptions method. An error pops up saying: Cannot resolve symbol 'menu'.
 Here is the code for that:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;

}
```

The error:

[image: Error]

Comment: try invalidate and cache

Comment: Not a fix solution but It happens due to some unexpected breaks. I go through with some steps and got my things done. 
1. Clean Project
2. Rebuild Project
3. Sync with Gradle file system
4. Invalidate cache and Restart 

It took some time to follow the steps one by one, But the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try these :

1. Check the import statement of `R`.
   It should be import .R NOT android.R
2. Clean & Rebuild.
3. Invalidate caches & restart.
4. Sometimes, the lint error might be wrong. Try installing & running the app on a device.
5. Check if both the file & its usage are in same module. Can cause issues if both files are in different modules.